# Does installing ASP.NET MVC on Windows 2003 require a server reboot?

Tags: asp.net, installation, mvc

Does installing ASP.NET MVC require a server reboot?

I've set up quite a few ASP.NET MVC sites on production servers in my time, but today, I'm deploying to a server without MVC installed for the first time.

So, I installed the latest MVC release, restarted the IIS and went through the usual hoops to set up a MVC website on IIS6 (aspnet_isapi.dll, setting the correct .NET version, etc).

However, the site behaves exactly like a non-MVC website. The root url clearly maps to default.aspx, but any controller/action urls all result in a 404.

I've had two colleagues check the site configuration, both giving thumbs up.

I won't reboot the server without a very good reason. Does any of you know, whether I need to reboot after installation of ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's never needed a reboot when I have installed it on either 2003 or 2008.